# Adding a new column from a match on two other data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I try to fill a new field **Status** to my **DF** from a match on two other data frames **DF1** and **DF2**.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CODE': ['REP', 'REP', 'NANQUE','NANQUE', 'AB_DEV'], 'name':['AUDI', 'AUDI', 'VW','MER','FIAT']})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'CODE': ['REP', 'NANQUE','AB_DEV'], 'status':['SORT/QUALT', 'ECHEC','OUTBAND']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['AUDI', 'AUDI','AUDI','VW','VW','MER','FIAT','FIAT','FIAT'], 
                    'status':['SORT', 'SORT','SORT','INCOM','INCOM','INCOM', 'OUTBAND','OUTBAND','OUTBAND'],
                   'CITY':['BOST', 'NY','WC','CH','WC','CH', 'NY','LA','CH']})
```

Here is my data frame **DF**

```
CODE    | name
---------------  
REP     | AUDI
REP     | AUDI
NANQUE  | VW
NANQUE  | MER
AB_DEV  | FIAT
```

The check is done with the following data frame **DF1**

```
CODE    | Status
------------------
REP     | SORT/QUAL
NANQUE  | ECHEC
AB_DEV  | OUTBAND
...
```

with the following condition :

```py
IF DF['CODE'].isin(DF1['CODE']) and DF1['Status']=='OUTBAND' :
    DF['Status']== 'OUTBAND'
```

If not the second check is done with the following data frame **DF2**

```
name   |    Status  |  CITY
----------------------------
AUDI   |   SORT     |  BOST
AUDI   |   SORT     |   NY
AUDI   |   SORT     |   WC
VW     |  INCOM     |   CH
VW     |  INCOM     |   WC
MER    |  INCOM     |   CH
FIAT   |  OUTBAND   |   NY
FIAT   |  OUTBAND   |   LA
FIAT   |  OUTBAND   |   CH
```

with the following condition :

```py
IF DF['name'] == DF2['name']:
    DF['Status']== DF2['Status']
```

the final result I'm trying to find

```
CODE    |  name  |   Status
-------------------------------
REP     |  AUDI  |    SORT
REP     |  AUDI  |    SORT
NANQUE  |   VW   |    INCOM
NANQUE  |   MER  |    INCOM
AB_DEV  |   FIAT |    OUTBAND
```

I've tried a np.wehre but it doesn't work. Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @AMC I tried to give a rather reproducible example I hope it will fit

Comment: Can you share the data in a more convenient format, so as to minimize the amount of work required to recreate the df?

Comment: @AMC  it is good I added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind doing this in several steps and generating a new data frame, it can be done using two different joints:

```py
# I generate some sample data frames to test my answer
df = pd.DataFrame({'CODE': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'name':['quality', 'sale', 'quality']})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'CODE': ['A', 'C'], 'status':['outbound', 'outbound']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['sale', 'quality'], 'status':['outbound', 'incoming']})

# Meet the first condition
df_joint = df.set_index('CODE').join(df1[df1.status == 'outbound'].set_index('CODE'), how='left')

# Meet the second condition
df_joint_2 = df_joint.reset_index().set_index('name').join(df2[['name', 'status']].drop_duplicates().set_index('name'), how='left', rsuffix='df2')

# Put indexes in order
df_joint_2 = df_joint_2.reset_index()

# Pass the second conditions to the rows where the first was not met
df_joint_2['status'] = df_joint_2['status'].fillna(df_joint_2.statusdf2) 

# Clean up
df_joint_2.drop(columns=['name', 'statusdf2'], inplace=True)
```

`df_joint_2` is your output df.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I appreciate it but as I said below I don't try to make a join because it doesn't match the condition to check IF DF['CODE'][i] == DF1['CODE'][j] and DF1['Status'][j] =='outband' THEN : DF[STATUS][i] = 'outband' Else IF DF['name'][i]= DF2['name'][k] THEN DF[STATUS][i] = DF2[STATUS][k]

Comment: @wysouf Those joins do match the conditions: the first join meets your first condition because the joining field is CODE (df.CODE == df1.CODE) and is done over those rows from df1 that have status = 'outbound' (df1.status = 'outbound'), and the second condition is met in the second join because the field to do the join on is 'name' (meaning df.name = df2.name). Look at it closely or try the code!

Comment: I tried your technique but it doesn't work the second join sends more value thanks anyway

Comment: it creates duplicates with much more data

Comment: Of course, if df2 has the `name` value repeated, it will create a match for each of them. But then you need to explain how you want to loop over your df2 when testing the second condition. If you provide more data about the length and characteristics of each df, maybe we can find a solution. On the other hand, depending on the duplicates created, you can always `df_joint_2.drop_duplicates(subset=[...])`

Comment: yes you are right I tried to give a more complete example tell me if it is clearer  thanks

Comment: Seeing the new data you have added to the question, we have to supposed that the conditions for df1 and df2 can only be true once per row, so in order not to produce non-desired duplicates, you need to reduce your df2 to unique rows. I have added the modification to my answer.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot for your time ! @msanzal